# Group data in row for calculation in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have received an Excel file with 4096 values, all in one row. I want to calculate the root mean square of each pair of 20 values but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do such a thing in Excel.

May I have some assistance?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a single value in each row, for 4096 rows?  And you want the RMS for every 20 rows?What is the formula?

Just for an example, if your values were in col A starting at row 1 and you wanted the mean (which I think is different than the RMS) you could merge the cells B1-B20 into one cell, then write the formula:

```
=SUM(A1:A20)/20.
```

Then, you click the cell and expand the merged cells down to the bottom and it would iterate the formula every 20th cell.  Hopefully I am not too far off of what you needed.

Comment: I ended up typing in the formula for the first 40 values and then filling the row with results. Then I deleted blank cells that got left over